# Cannot insert into a non-nullable column

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have the code below setup as an Automation in Marketing Cloud.

- B.Subscriber_Key *is* a nullable column.
- A.SUBSCRIBER_KEY *is not* a nullable column.

I only want B.Subscriber_Key to be updated with the value from A.SUBSCRIBER_KEY and that is working, but I keep getting an error in the end that says "Cannot insert a NULL value into a non-nullable column".  It doesn't specify the column or value in question.  How can I fix this?

```
SELECT B.EMAIL, 
CASE WHEN B.SUBSCRIBER_KEY IS null THEN A.SUBSCRIBER_KEY
ELSE B.Subscriber_Key
END AS SUBSCRIBER_KEY
FROM ent.main_subscriber A
LEFT JOIN ent.newsletter B
ON A.EMAIL = B.EMAIL
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be that `Subscriber_Key` is not always populated in the `newsletter` DE.

You can handle that with the [coalesce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function and a check in the where-clause:

```sql
SELECT 
B.EMAIL
, coalesce(b.SubscriberKey, a.subscriber_key) AS SUBSCRIBER_KEY
FROM ent.main_subscriber A
LEFT JOIN ent.newsletter B ON A.EMAIL = B.EMAIL
where coalesce(b.SubscriberKey, a.subscriber_key) is not null
and b.email is not null
```

Coalesce just means "give me the first non-null value in this list of comma-separated of fields".

Comment: I think this did it.  Thank you!

Comment: If this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark on the left. [Accepted answers](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) indicate to the community that you've found a solution (and it increases the reputation of both of us).